# Node.js, Express and Mongoose, undefined data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Just a noob problem:

I'm trying to use the property "cover" to delete a file related to that collection, but the problem is that it show as "undefined". Did anyone had a problem like this ?? Thanks !!!

**Here is my Log:**

FULL RESULT - { __v: 0,
  _id: 5329a730e4b6306a08297318,

company: 'asd',

**cover**: '44f4a87035bd22c1995dcf0ab8af05b0',

description: 'asd',

kind: 'asd',

name: 'asd' }

RESULT COVER - **undefined**

**Here is my code:**

```
exports.delete = function(req,res){

if(!req.session.authorized){
    res.json(403,{message:'YOU MUST BE LOGGED IN'});
    return;
}


Product.find({_id:req.params.id}, function(err,result){

    if (err){
        res.json(401, {message: err});

    }else{
        console.log("FULL RESULT - " + result);
        console.log("RESULT COVER - " + result.cover);

        var prodCoverName = result.cover;

        if (prodCoverName){

            fs.exists('public/productAssets/'+ prodCoverName, function (exists) {
                console.log('EXIST - public/productAssets/'+ prodCoverName);
                fs.unlink('public/productAssets/'+ prodCoverName, function (err) {

                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('DELETED AT public/productAssets/'+ prodCoverName);

                });

            });

        }

    } 

});

Product.findOneAndRemove({_id:req.params.id}, function(err,result){

    if (err) res.json(401, {message: err});
    else res.json(200, {message: result});

});
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not expert in mongoose, but my guess is that [`Product.find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) function, will call it's callback with an array of documents, instead of a single document, So you should change your code with the following:

```
Product.find({_id:req.params.id}, function(err, results){
   var result = results[0]; // either one result or nothing, because id is unique and we want the first result only.
```

Or use [findOne](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) instead(this one callbacks with the first result, faster):

```
Product.findOne({_id:req.params.id}, function(err, result){
```

Or use [findById](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)(shorter and faster):

```
Product.findById(req.params.id, function(err, result){
```

Now you might ask, why in my case, FULL RESULT, is an object. Here's what happens in javascript:

You have `console.log("FULL RESULT - " + result)`, here you are logging a string and you have string concatenation operation, between a string and an array. When you trying to concat a string with a non-string, javascript tries to coerce it into a string, so on cases where it's not undefined/null it will call [`.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method of the value. [`.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method of an array actually does `return this.join(',')`. [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method is also a string concatenation. The array contains documents, so javascript tries to convert the documents into strings(they are objects actually) and it calls the [`document.toString()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toString). That is implemented by mongoose to return the object properties, which should be something similar to `util.inpsect(document);`. Another example to this incident is getting `result is 1` from `'result is ' + [1]`.

To avoid this problem, I suggest, just avoid concatenting objects with strings. Instead of `console.log('result is ' + object)` try to do `console.log(object)` or `console('result is', object)`.

Update:

I just realized you are also calling findOneAndRemove at the same time you are calling find, this is a race condition. It might happen that `.find` call wouldn't find anything, because `.findOneAndRemove` might have been already done. This might introduce more problems.

Comment: I've changed by Product.findById(req.params.id, function(err, result){  as you said... it is working perfectly now....I'll try to make one call only to make to avoid future problems.. Thanks for the explanation !!  Thanks a lot! really appreciated!!! XD

Comment: Your welcome, in future try not to concatenate strings with objects so this confusion won't happen again.